# Html5: {{data}} to be placed in middle of text coming from json file

Tags: json, angular, html

I have a question related to html and angular5.

```
<span [innerHTML]="'client.acceptance.explanation'| translate"></span>
<span><b>{{data}}</b></span>
```

Here 'client.acceptance.explanation' text is in a json file and data is being taken and appended with the text. For example if my text is :
Dear {{data}}, Please confirm your are ready to review. Now i want to take the data in the middle of my text. So half text is before {{data}} and half text is after it.
So how would i specify that in html5??

Comment: Maybe you will have to slice your text in two parts (in your JSON file), especially if you use a translation pipe: `{{part1 | translate}} {{data}} {{part2 | translate}}`

Comment: You could also just fall back on good ole' string replace via another custom pipe. Something like: `'client.acceptance.explanation'| translate | replace:{data: data}`

Comment: What library translation library do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide the process in 2 steps using pipe:
1. Translate the text coming from json file
2. Give the translated data as input for the formatting pipe to generate the final text.

Check out the below code:
**HTML:**

{{'client.acceptance.explanation'| translate | formatData}}

**PIPE:**

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'formatData'
})
export class FormatDataPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(input: string) {
    return `Dear ${{ input }}, Please confirm your are ready to review`;
  }
}
```